# How to fix Carthage the dependency graph contained a cycle?

Tags: ios, carthage

I use Carthage in my project

Contents of Cartfile:

```
#socket.io-client
github "socketio/socket.io-client-swift" ~> 13.1.0
```

Contents of Cartfile.resolved

```
github "daltoniam/Starscream" "3.0.5"
github "socketio/socket.io-client-swift" "v13.1.3"
```

When I run `carthage update --platform ios`

```
I get the following output:
*** Fetching socket.io-client-swift
*** Fetching Starscream
*** Checking out socket.io-client-swift at "v13.1.3"
*** Checking out Starscream at "3.0.5"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in ...
The dependency graph contained a cycle:
socket.io-client-swift: Starscream
Starscream: zlib-spm, common-crypto-spm
```

My Carthage version is `0.29.0`

Judging by the output there is no cycle in the dependencies

How can this be resolved?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, also with socket.io. Any solution?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I finally got it to build again by simply deleting the Carthage folder and running `carthage update` again

Comment: yes, I removed too folder `Carthage` and file `cartfile.resolved` before execute command `Carthage update ...`

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to also remove Carthage's cache additionally to the Carthage folder:

```
$ rm -rf ./Carthage
$ rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit
```